# VNC screensaver & locker: missing XInput extensions

Tags: vnc, xinput, xscreensaver, tightvnc

I use a vnc (`tightvncserver`) connection: `Devuan/aarch64` and `Armbian(Debian)/armfh` (hosts) thru Win10/TigerVNC (client).

Since the upgrade of the underlying base to Debian Bookworm, `xscreensaver` and any other locker fail to run for the same reason:

```
xscreensaver --no-splash
xscreensaver: 12:09:54: XInput extension missing

xtrlock -f
xtrlock (version 2.15): No X Input extension
```

I reached out the **Xscreensaver** developer, and he told me the Debian package brings with it all the necessary dependencies, and he doesn't know where the problem is.

I also installed a bunch of additional packages but nothing has changed:

```
libx11-xcb1/stable-security,now 2:1.8.4-2+deb12u2 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-damage0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-dri2-0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-dri3-0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-glx0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-icccm4/stable,now 0.4.1-1.1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-image0/stable,now 0.4.0-2 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-keysyms1/stable,now 0.4.0-1+b2 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-present0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-randr0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-render-util0/stable,now 0.3.9-1+b1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-render0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-screensaver0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed]
libxcb-shape0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-shm0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-sync1/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-util1/stable,now 0.4.0-1+b1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-xfixes0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-xinerama0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-xinput0/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb-xkb1/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb1-dev/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libxcb1/stable,now 1.15-1 arm64 [installed,automatic]
```

On `Bullseye`, `xscreensaver` and other lockers were working just fine, I can't figure out how to fix this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue, in the terms that I found a screen locker that works on the VNC session.

As a matter of fact [slock](https://tools.suckless.org/slock/) from the `suckless-tools` works without complaining.

To trigger it I use `xautolock` in combination with the `slock`.

If you are on a `Debian` based `GNU/Linux` distribution you can install them with:

```
# apt install suckless-tools xautolock
```

This is my `.vnc/xstartup`

```
.vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/sh

# Load X resources (if any)
if [ -e "$HOME/.Xresources" ]
then
        xrdb "$HOME/.Xresources"
fi

#
xsetroot -solid black
xmodmap -e "keysym Alt_L = Multi_key" &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry "80x24+10+10" -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
xautolock -time 1 -locker slock &
```

The last line is the command that launch the aforementioned packages in background.